# How to run jmeter in non GUI mode with client cert file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Currently running jmeter in GUI mode with importing client cert file thru option-SSL Manager this works fine without any issue.

But How do i run jmeter in non GUI mode with Client cert file?

Note - If client cert file is not imported in jmeter while running, we get 403 forbidden error

Note - I'm using Jmeter 5.0 version

Much need help on this
Please share any links and videos with step by step procedure

Answer (score 2):

You can "tell" JMeter to use the certificates for client-side requests encryption by manipulating system properties, i.e. add the next lines to [*system.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl):

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 (or jks)
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/keystore
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your keystore password
```

Next time you start JMeter it will use the keystore provided for requests encryption.

Alternatively you [can pass the same parameters via -D command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 (or jks) -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your keystore password -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

More information: [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)

Comment: Currently cert file is in .pfx format...          
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 (or jks) - 
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/keystore
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your keystore password                                                       How do i get above mentioned points , i have gone thru the links could not able to understand since i'm new to jmeter. If you give any example with details how much appreciated

Comment: [`pfx` is a `pkcs12` format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12), I believe I've given you all the examples and instructions.